# Fetch records from Firestore for pagination - Ionic/Angular

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying as per the docs to fetch first 25 records from Firestore like this.

Note: my requirement is to fetch the `first 25` records which I am trying using `current25 = documentSnapshots.docs;` , it is not returning me the array of 25 records.

```
var first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {

// *** I am stuck here as I am not getting the array ***
var current25 = documentSnapshots.docs;
  console.log(current25);
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(25);
});
```

Comment: Hi user2828442. I've edited a lot of chatty material from your questions in the past, and you will have received the notifications from the Stack Overflow platform. Some of your material has a needy, begging quality, and suggests you think that displays of helplessness will cause people to pity your situation and/or feel coerced into the social obligation of assisting the less fortunate. This is not appropriate behaviour for a volunteer platform. Please stick to technical writing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a promise because you are not giving enough time to the promise to be resolved. In order to solve your issue, you have to make your function **async** and **await** the promise to get the documents.

```
async function yourfunction(...){

   var first = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .limit(25);

   const documentSnapshots = await first.get();


   var current25 = documentSnapshots.docs;
   console.log(current25);
   // Get the last visible document
   var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
   console.log("last", lastVisible);


   // Construct a new query starting at this document,
   // get the next 25 cities.
   var next = db.collection("cities")
        .orderBy("population")
        .startAfter(lastVisible)
        .limit(25);

   return "What you want to return";
}
```